# Example of the five-lemma -- hatcher exercise 2.1.31

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

So the five lemma asserts if we have the following commutative diagram
$$ 
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A & ^{i}\longrightarrow & B & ^{j}\longrightarrow & C & ^{k}\longrightarrow & D & ^{\ell}\longrightarrow & E \\
\downarrow_{\alpha} & \phantom{{i}\longrightarrow} & \downarrow_{\beta} & \phantom{^{j}\longrightarrow} & \downarrow_{\gamma} & \phantom{^{k}\longrightarrow}& \downarrow_{\delta} & \phantom{^{\ell}\longrightarrow E} & \downarrow_{\epsilon}\\
A' & ^{i'}\longrightarrow & B' & ^{j'}\longrightarrow & C' & ^{k'}\longrightarrow & D' & ^{\ell'}\longrightarrow & E' \\
\end{array}
$$
and the two rows are exact and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$ are isomorphisms, then $\gamma$ is an isomorphism also.

I am trying to complete exercise 2.1.31 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* which asks to give an example where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$ are zero but $\gamma$ is nonzero. The text also offers a hint that this can be done by finding short exact sequences where all groups are 0 or $\mathbb{Z}$. I am having a hard time seeing how this could be true, so I want to clarify a few things.

If I want to make the top (or bottom) row a short exact sequence, then do I need to impose that A and E (or A' and E') equal to 0?

Also when they say $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$ are zero, does they mean that the are equal to the identity map? Because I interpret the zero map as the homomorphism that sends everything to the identity. If we want $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$ to be isomorphisms, then that does not exactly give me a lot of room for selecting $A,A', B, B', D, D', E,E'$....

Comment: (1) Yes, need to make $A,A',E,E'$ all $0$ for the sequences to be short exact. (2) The "identity map" $f(x)=x$ certainly does not send all $x$ to the identity element $0$.

Comment: @arctictern But my issue is if I make $B,B'$ (and others as well) nontrivial, then then zero map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: How is that an issue?

Comment: @arctictern Maybe I am misreading the question, but am I not supposed to essentially give a specific $A,A', \dots$ etc. and maps $i, i', \dots$, etc where satisfying all of the conditions of the five lemma? My understanding is that $\alpha$, $\beta$, etc. all need to be isomorphisms.

Comment: While the problem says "using the notation of the five lemma," it says nothing about satisfying the hypotheses of the lemma. Obviously zero maps will not be isomorphisms (except $0\to 0$).

Comment: @arctictern so basically just make a commutative diagram where the 4 outer, vertical maps are simply homomorphisms?

Comment: Where the four outer, vertical maps are *zero* (meaning the zero map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hatcher says we can use short exact sequences and only $0$s and $\mathbb{Z}$s. Let's try.

To be short exact, we need $A,A',E,E'$ to be $0$. We want $\gamma$ to be a nonzero isomorphism, which means we need $C$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$. So we have

$$ \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 0 & \longrightarrow & B & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow & D & \longrightarrow & 0 \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ 0 & \longrightarrow & B' & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow & D' & \longrightarrow & 0 \end{array} $$

We already know what all of the down arrows are: the outer four are zero maps, and the middle one is an isomorphism, so the identity map. In order for the sequences to be exact, we need both sets $\{B,D\}$ and $\{B',D'\}$ to be $\{0,\mathbb{Z}\}$. But which to make which? I'll let you try that.

Comment: So setting $B = D' = 0$, $B' = D = \mathbb{Z}$ works.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.